# Index thru a List of Lists in AutoLISP

Tags: autolisp

I have a list of lists of integers:

```
(setq a '(21 14 35 29 16 28))
(setq b '(15 36 21 17 45 41))
(setq c '(24 21 35 28 17 21))
```

There could be 50 +/- lists total.

I have another list:

```
(setq me '(17 14 31 21 17 28))
```

I want to cycle through the initial list of lists and subtract each member of list `a` (1st time thru) from list `me`.

How would I be able to index thru the initial list of lists so that I can perform the comparison?

Answer (score 1):

If I pretend to understand what you're asking ...

```
(setq 
    a  '(21 14 35 29 16 28)
    b  '(15 36 21 17 45 41)
    c  '(24 21 35 28 17 21)
    me '(17 14 31 21 17 28)
    lst (append a b c)
)

(setq result 
    (vl-remove-if
       '(lambda (x) (member x lst))
        me
    )
)
```

result's value is (31)

if that ^ was what you were looking for then a more generic solution:

```
(defun foo ( lst listOfLists )
    (   (lambda ( grandList )
            (vl-remove-if
               '(lambda (x) (member x grandList))
                lst
            )
        )
        (apply 'append listOfLists)
    )        
)

(foo me (list a b c))
```

returns (31)